# Entity Framework 6.1.3 Lazy Loading behaving inconsistently

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a project which is using code first entities.

The following test passes:-

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLazyLoadNewEntity()
{
    MyContext context = new MyContext();
    UserRoleEntity entity = context.Set<UserRoleEntity>().Create();
    entity.RoleID = 1;
    context.Set<UserRoleEntity>().Add(entity);
    Assert.IsNotNull(entity.Role);
}
```

This test fails:-

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLazyLoadNewEntity2()
{
    MyContext context = new MyContext();
    UserRoleEntity entity = context.Set<UserRoleEntity>().Create();
    context.Set<UserRoleEntity>().Add(entity);
    entity.RoleID = 1;
    Assert.IsNotNull(entity.Role);
}
```

In both cases it is definitely creating proxied entities, the type is e.g.

> entity type is
>   {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.UserRoleRelationEnti_02312836F5B832353B301D531F352923C7A344A83045D8155F462D8BE23A5A53}

The difference in the order in which the entity is added and the ID assigned, affects lazy loading of the navigation property.  In both cases I can see in SQL profiler that a query to load the role is executed, however in the second case it fails to result in the navigation property being loaded.

Is this expected behavior? I'm pretty certain previous versions of EF did not behave as such.

EDIT: as suggested [pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168070/pawel) adding a call to DetectChanges does make the test pass.  So it's looking more like this is expected behavior rather than a bug.  Which is unfortunate for me as I've got a code base that once used EDMX generated entities which did not require such a call.  I'm wishing there was another solution as the implications are I have broken code in a large code base which will be difficult to find

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLazyLoadNewEntity2()
{
    MyContext context = new MyContext();
    UserRoleEntity entity = context.Set<UserRoleEntity>().Create();
    context.Set<UserRoleEntity>().Add(entity);
    entity.RoleID = 1;
    context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    Assert.IsNotNull(entity.Role);
}
```

Comment: Can it be that relationship is not fixed up when the id is 0. If you called `DetectChanges` would the test pass?

Comment: @Pawel thanks, you are correct, calling DetectChanges() does cause the test to pass. Although I'm wishing there was another solution as the implications are I may have broken code in a large code base which might be difficult to find.

Comment: This is how EF works. When you add an entity it will try to fix up relationships but since you first added the entity with the (default) id value of 0 there apparently was nothing to fix up. Then you changed the id but EF was not aware of it (I think if you used change tracking proxies EF would have noticed and fix up relationships). DetectChanges is called automatically when you SaveChanges so in real world nothing would be broken.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the proxies would implement interfaces like INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged.  Then it would be trivial.  The fact that it actually does a sql query and just doesn't load the results into the navigation property still has me thinking this isn't really right.  I'm surprised this is how EF code first proxies work.